# Is there a way to check the difference (what did change) between two MacOS (Catalina) TimeMachine snapshots?

Tags: macos, time-machine, macos-catalina

As per subject, suppose I have two consecutive TimeMachine local snapshots on my Mac: is there a way to e.g. mount both them and compare ? I.e. to know what files have been changed from the between the former and the latter snapshot ?

Answer (score 1):

The `tmutil` command-line tool has a `compare` option that does this.

Give it the file paths to the two snapshot folders on the backup volume to compare.
It will be easier to `cd` to the backup parent, then just specify the snapshots.

For example:

```
cd "/Volumes/Backup Disk/Backups.backupdb/Ipinak's Mac"
tmutil compare 2016-03-27-101112 2016-03-26-174321
```

([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232695/find-differences-between-time-machine-backups))

The simplest command compares the most recent Time Machine snapshop with what is currently on the Mac:

```
tmutil compare
```

Comment: Thanks Harry, this might do for my needs, though I was aiming at comparing local snapshots and it seems tmutil compare won't work with those. Anyway, I learned of this command's existence with your answer so, though it's going to take some time (first full backup to USB disk plus subsequent ones I need to compare), I will eventually try those. Thanks!